# Matlab: Create vector of arrays

Tags: matlab

I am a python (and numpy) regular who just started using Matlab. I am solving boundary value problems using `bv4pc`, and I want to store the result arrays, solved for different parameters, in a larger array.

For example, consider the following code that returns a result vector `y` for each value of the parameter `t` -

```
for j = 1:loops
    t = 1/(sqrt(2).^j)
    % solve ODE that depends on parameter t
    sol = bvp4c(@(x,y)elasticaODE(x,y,t),@(ya,yb)elasticaBC(ya,yb,t),solinit,options);

    % The solution at the mesh points
    x = sol.x;
    y = sol.y;
```

In python, I would just do:

```
yVector = []
for (t in tArray):
    ... solve ODE, get y ...
    yVector.append(y)
yVector = np.array(yVector)
```

What is the equivalent in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matlab, most variables are matrices by default. There are two exceptions that might be what you are looking for:

**1- Cells**

Cells are similar to Python arrays, in the sense that each element can be anything

`my_cell = {'a', 1, "wut", [1,2,3]};`

And you can access the elements using the curly braces notation:

`my_cell{1} % yields 'a'`

`my_cell{4}(2) % yields 2`

**2-Struct Arrays**

You can define a struct by declaring it's fields, and they are mutable, a bit like in a Python dictionary:

`my_struct.a = 1`
`my_struct.b = 2`

If you have structs with the same fields, you can create a vector of structs:

`my_second_struct.a = 3`
`my_second_struct.b = 4`

`my_vector_of_structs = [my_struct; my_second_struct]`

Again, each field in a struct can be anything, even another struct.

Comment: Yes, cells are what I am looking for.